# ERRO findViewById ListView fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-fragment

Ola, estou com um problema que não consigo resolver, criei uma list view mas ao "chama-la" no Java (tem uma seta abaixo) resulta em erro ao testar a aplicação, este é o erro:

```
08-04 19:59:25.765: D/skia(23307): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 270 
08-04 19:59:25.775: D/skia(23307): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 271 
08-04 19:59:25.805: I/PersonaManager(23307): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
08-04 19:59:25.845: I/PersonaManager(23307): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
08-04 19:59:25.855: D/skia(23307): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 272 
08-04 19:59:25.875: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(23307): Parent view is not a TextView
08-04 19:59:25.895: D/skia(23307): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 273 
08-04 19:59:25.895: I/PersonaManager(23307): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
08-04 19:59:26.125: D/AndroidRuntime(23307): Shutting down VM
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): Process: com.sapires.Pizza, PID: 23307
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.sapires.Joes.Ementa.onCreateView(Ementa.java:46)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2262)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-04 19:59:26.145: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
```

Este é o Java:

```
    package com.sapires.Joes;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.sapires.Pizza.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Ementa extends Fragment {

    String[] titulos;
    String[] descricoes;
    int[] images = { R.drawable.um, R.drawable.dois, R.drawable.tres,
            R.drawable.quatro };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ementa_2, container, false);

        Resources res = getResources();
        titulos = res.getStringArray(R.array.titulos);
        descricoes = res.getStringArray(R.array.descricoes);

    ->  ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        return android;
    }

}

class VivzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    VivzAdapter(Context c, String[] titulos){
        super(c,R.layout.ementa_2, R.id.textView1, titulos);
    }

}
```

Este é o layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5B92E5" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/um" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já inflou sua view em `onCreateView`, porém o método ainda não retornou a view inflada. Então o método `getView()` irá retornar null, pois ainda não há view que retornar. Por isso ocorre NullPointerException. Você, ao invéz disso, pode usar diretamente a instancia da sua view inflada em `onCreateView`.

Substitua a linha:

```
ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

por:

```
ListView list = (ListView) android.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Ou então pode usar o método `onViewCreated` para isso:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
     ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
}
```

Espero que isso resolva o problema!

Comment: Resolveu, 5 estrelas, muito obrigado, percebi porque não funcionava.